# psycopg2 is not getting imported in AWS glue job 3.0

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, aws-glue

AS mentioned in lot of questions in stackoverflow I tried importing psycopg2 using --additional-python-modules = psycopg2-binary==2.9.1 and --python-modules-installer-option = --upgrade

But getting following error :

```
INFO    2023-06-13 10:11:51,045 111399  com.amazonaws.services.glue.PythonModuleInstaller   [main]  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/psycopg2-binary/WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/psycopg2-binary/WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/psycopg2-binary/WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/psycopg2-binary/WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/psycopg2-binary/ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg2_binary==2.9.1 (from versions: none)ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg2_binary==2.9.1
```

How can I install module